# create objects based on elements of a list

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have the below lists and data classes in Kotlin:

```
val qrtr = listOf("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")

data class X(val name: String, val location: String)
val x1 = X("John Doe", "USA")
val x2 = X("Jane Doe", "Singapore")
val allX = listOf(x1, x2)

data class Y(val title: String, val rating: Double)
val y1 = Y("Senior", 4.8)
val y2 = Y("Junior", 4.5)
val allY = listOf(y1, y2)
```

Is there an easy way to create another list using a 3rd data class using the above lists of allX, allY and qrtr.

```
data class Z(val x: X, val y: Y, quarter: String)
```

For the above data class (Z), I would like to merge details of `allX` and `allY` by its index position..and have this data repeated for each element in `qrtr`.

If it were to be done manually, it would look like this: But I'd like it done programmatically.

```
val z1 = Z(x1, y1, "Q1")
val z2 = Z(x1, y1, "Q2")
val z3 = Z(x1, y1, "Q3")
val z4 = Z(x1, y1, "Q4")
val z5 = Z(x2, y2, "Q1")
val z6 = Z(x2, y2, "Q2")
val z7 = Z(x2, y2, "Q3")
val z8 = Z(x2, y2, "Q4")
val allZ = listOf(z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val result = allX.zip(allY).flatMap { (x, y) -> qrtr.map { q -> Z(x, y, q) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
val allZ = allX.flatMapIndexed { index, x -> qrtr.map { q -> Z(x, allY[index], q) } }
allZ.forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

Output:

```
Z(x=X(name=John Doe, location=USA), y=Y(title=Senior, rating=4.8), quarter=Q1)
Z(x=X(name=John Doe, location=USA), y=Y(title=Senior, rating=4.8), quarter=Q2)
Z(x=X(name=John Doe, location=USA), y=Y(title=Senior, rating=4.8), quarter=Q3)
Z(x=X(name=John Doe, location=USA), y=Y(title=Senior, rating=4.8), quarter=Q4)
Z(x=X(name=Jane Doe, location=Singapore), y=Y(title=Junior, rating=4.5), quarter=Q1)
Z(x=X(name=Jane Doe, location=Singapore), y=Y(title=Junior, rating=4.5), quarter=Q2)
Z(x=X(name=Jane Doe, location=Singapore), y=Y(title=Junior, rating=4.5), quarter=Q3)
Z(x=X(name=Jane Doe, location=Singapore), y=Y(title=Junior, rating=4.5), quarter=Q4)
```

Note that it will crash though if `allX` has more elements than `allY`